# How do I test specific viewports using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

In my app, I use a media query to conditionally show a shorter string if the device is not large enough to show the full string:

```
const mobile = window.matchMedia(
  '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 820px)'
)?.matches;
const str = mobile ? 'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZ' : 'ABCDEFGHIKLM';
...
```

I am trying to test different viewport sizes to see if the full string or just a partial one is shown.

In my test, I am mocking the resolution of an iPhone 13 Pro and trying to assert that only the smaller string is showing:

```
it('should show partial string in element', () => {
  window.innerWidth = 1170;
  window.innerHeight = 2532;
  window.devicePixelRatio = 4;

  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  expect(window.innerWidth).toBe(1170);

  const element = screen.getByTestId('element');
  expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/^ABCDEFGHIKLM$/);
});
```

However, the test is failing because the full string (`ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZ`) is shown instead of the partial one. Also, when I pull up an emulator in the browser, only the partial string is shown. How can I test for elements based on the viewports size using Jest?